# Using 'lower_bound'

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int t;
cin >> t;
for (int i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    long int ar[n];
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) cin >> ar[j];
    vector<long> v(ar, ar+n);
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    for (int k = 0; k < m; ++k) {
        long b;
        cin >> b;
        if (binary_search(v.begin(), v.end(), b)) cout << "YES" << endl;
        else {
            vector<int>::iterator it;
            it=lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), b);
            v.insert(it-v.begin(), b);
            cout << "NO" << endl;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

the compiler shows error at 'it=lower_bound(______)' and at '(it-v.begin(),b)' .
I can't understand. please help me in sorting this out.

```
[Error] no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::vector<int>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >}' and '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long int*, std::vector<long int> >')

[Error] no match for 'operator-' (operand types are 'std::vector<int>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >}' and 'std::vector<long int>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long int*, std::vector<long int> >}')
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

With the error message it's easier to find the error.

```
[Error] no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::vector<int>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >}' and '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long int*, std::vector<long int> >')
```

You got a type mismatch. One iterator is into a `vector<int>` the other into a `vector<long>`. See:

```
vector<long> v(ar, ar+n); // the vector you declare.

vector<int>::iterator it; // the iterator you want to save the element location in.
```

You have to decide on a single type here. Do you have `int`'s or `long`'s?

Your call to [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) is also a bit wrong. The first argument shouldn't be an index like you seem to think, it's supposed to be an iterator to the location you want to insert it. So just call it like:

```
v.insert(it, b); // we don't have to subtract `v.begin()`.
```

---

Going over it again after some sleep, here are some additional comments.

```
cin >> n >> m;
long int ar[n];
```

here you read the size of an array from the input. This is a compiler extension, it isn't standard C++. Arrays got to have their size known at compile time in C++. Use `std::vector` instead. Your using it already anyways.

```
long int ar[n];
for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) cin >> ar[j];
vector<long> v(ar, ar+n);
```

As you're using `std::vector` anyways, there's no need for the array. Especially since it's making use of a compiler extension like I said above. Change it to

```
vector<long> v(n);
for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) cin >> v[j];
```

Last but not least use better variable names. All your variables are 1 or 2 characters long. This makes it hard to follow code, even with relatively few lines and becomes absolutely terrible once it gets bigger. There is no reason to use such short variable names in C++, use longer and descriptive ones.

Comment: I'd like to add two things: The first is the bad habit of splitting declaration of a variable (`vector<int>::iterator it;`) and assigning a value to it `it = lower_bound(...);`), those should be merged. Further, with C++11, that should just be `auto it = lower_bound(...);`.